# Updating Store Before Custom Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am designing react application with node server. I have created a custom Private Route

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component{
    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

        return (
            <Route {...rest} component={(props) => {
                if(isAuthenticated){
                    return <Component {...props}/>
                }
                else{
                    return <Redirect to="/login" />
                }
            }}/>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.email !== '' ? true : false
    }
}

const ConnectedPrivateRoute = connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)
export default ConnectedPrivateRoute;
```

I am redirecting myself to dashboard route from node serer after login.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { setAuthenticatedUser } from '../actions/authA';

class Dashboard extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    axios.get('/cookie').then((user) => {
      if(user.data.email)
        this.props.dispatch(setAuthenticatedUser(user.data));
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("Got some error");
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Dashboard Page</div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(Dashboard);
```

Currently my dashboard looks for cookie about authentication and update my store.But after adding `custom route` there happens a redirection to `login page` that's because my custom route doesnot find the updated `store` since it is updated in dashboard. I am stuck here. I tried updating in my custom route but I added more confusion to myself. Any suggestion and solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you post your `Login` component, I could better answer the question.

Having said that, it is not the responsibility of the dashboard component to `setAuthenticatedUser`, since, if they are able to navigate to the dashboard, it means they are ALREADY authenticated.

After a user logs in, you should call `setAuthenticatedUser`, then redirect to the dashboard, that way your `PrivateRoute` component won't force a needless redirect.

Comment: yes that was previous attempt to get started with my setup. I was looking for the same as you stated. and Fortunately I managed to get the thing correct using local storage. Thanks for answering.